# How to create regex @mention at current cursor location

Tags: ios, regex, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to find regex that replace @mention at only current cursor location. with below regex it replacing all @mention available in textView. also I have tried with `pattern = "\\s\\@[a-z]+\\s"` but still failed.

```
func replace() {
    let pattern = "@[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+?(?![a-zA-Z0-9_.])"
    let txt = textView.text
    let length = textView.text.characters.count
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
    let newString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: txt!, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, length), withTemplate: "@\(userName)")
    textView.text = newString

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to replate all of the `@.` ?

Comment: no, replace only at current cursor only. let we have txt = "hi '@jason' please meet '@dave'". if cursor located at end of '@dave', so it will only replace '@dave'.

Comment: cursor?   what about cursor?

Comment: what do you mean 'what about cursor'? in a UITextView, a blinking indicator showing where typed text will be inserted.